# How to hint Python function with an inplace argument?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a function that takes and `inplace` argument. Following good practice, the function returns `None` if it modifies the input (`inplace=True`) and returns a copy of the input, modified, otherwise (`inplace=False`). (My preference now would be to just not have the `inplace` argument, but that ship sailed.)

I typed the function like this:

```
from typing import Union
A = TypeVar("A")
def func(data: A, inplace=False) -> Union[A, None]:
    if inplace:
        return None
    ...
    return data.copy()
```

But the following has a typing error:

```
modified_data = func([1, 2,3])
modified_data.append(4)
```

Saying that None Type objects don't have an append attritbute. This is correct: the type checker should, given the way the hint is written, say this is wrong, since we don't know the type of `modified_data` (given the type hints).

But this is obnoxious and we want the type checker to handle this case and raise a typing if inplace==True but not otherwise. Is there a way to handle it?

Comment: So you want the type checker to say it is OK to call 'append" on a value that might be `None`?

Comment: Don't use an argument for this, use a separate function or method.

Comment: @kindal The code is already in the public API for the function, so that's not an option. What is an option is to refactor the type hints.

Comment: @ScottHunter Not exactly. I would like the typing system to associate the literal value False for inplace with the type A for the return, and None otherwise. See the accepted answer, which shows how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@overload` (details [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#function-overloading)). But for your example it would look like this:

```py
from typing import List, Literal, Union, TypeVar, overload

A = TypeVar("A")

@overload
def func(data: List[A], inplace: Literal[True]) -> None: ...

@overload
def func(data: List[A], inplace: Literal[False] = ...) -> List[A]: ...

def func(data: List[A], inplace: bool=False) -> Union[List[A], None]:
    if inplace:
        return None
    
    return data.copy()


modified_data = func([1, 2,3])
modified_data.append(4)

func(modified_data, inplace=True)
```

#### The explanation:

We define overloads for the function, that will be used by mypy type checker. The first case is that if `inplace=True` (hence `Literal[True]`) then there is no output `None`.

```py
@overload
def func(data: List[A], inplace: Literal[True]) -> None: ...
```

When the `inplace=False`, we have the output of `List[A]` (I replaced `A` with `List[A]`, because arbitrary `A` doesn't implement `.copy()`). Note the `...` in `inplace: Literal[False] = ...` as this is our default case for this function.

```py
@overload
def func(data: List[A], inplace: Literal[False] = ...) -> List[A]: ...
```

Then you can use Mypy to see if there are any errors. In my case this whole example that I provided does not return any errors.